# CSS background url not showing up

Tags: css, image, background

I just finished making my code live & all of a sudden the Logo won't show anymore. (It was working fine on my Browser Stimulator.) If anyone knows what I did wrong please let me know, a website is not much use if the logo isn't showing up!!

CSS:

```
#header {
height: 150px;
margin-left: 15px;
background-image: url('../images/headings/header.gif');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
text-align: right;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-right: 50px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="header">
<a href="realtors.htm">Realtors Click Here</a><br /><br /><br /><br />
<p><a href="http://www.facebook.com/PrimaResidential"><img src="images/headings/facebook.png" alt="Facebook" width="100" height="70" /></a></p>
<p><a href="https://twitter.com/Prima_Updates"><img src="images/headings/twitter.png" alt="Twitter" width="100" height="70" /></a></p>
<p><a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/prima_residential"><img src="images/headings/flickr.png" alt="Flickr" width="100" height="70" /></a></p>
</div>
```

Everything else in the header works just fine, I just don't know why the image won't work! 
The logo is the background-image in the CSS incase anyone was looking for it!

Thanks!!

Comment: just check if the `image url` for the `background image` is correct i.e if the image is loading or it failed to load

Comment: `../images/headings/header.gif` would be relative to where the css file resides, or if its inline with the page, then relative to the page.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your paths are right? I see your other images are being loaded from images/headings/. Try changing ../images/ to images/ in your CSS.

Comment: I did that about three for four times just to make sure... but no luck

Comment: @ashleigh Can you try with absolute paths?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out!! For some reason when I downloaded the zipped file there were a few items that were not fully loaded and the header.gif happened to be one of them. I just redownloaded the .gif & it works perfectly now! Thanks for everyones suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the image is located in the **correct folder** or directory. You may also try opening image directly from server using browser and may use that url to your CSS like;

```
background-image: url('http://yourserver.com/dir1/dir2/header.gif');
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the path of image folder.As you are saying it's working on your local machine, So I guess you have images folder in the parent folder of your css class. Check if same is applicable after deployment.

Comment: I moved it to the css folder & still no luck!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this
**

> background-image: url('/images/headings/header.gif');

---

**

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```css
background-image: url('../../images/headings/header.gif');
```